# How to issue a dividend in Stellar?

Tags: token

Is it possible to create custom token XYZ and issue XYZ token dividends via the XYZ distributor account to all XYZ token holders, and what is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

1. Deploy your own [Stellar Core](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/admin.html) node.
2. Query `trustlines` table of the underlying database directly to retrieve a list of your asset holders and the amount they hold.
3. Split the list in batches, 100 accounts per batch.
4. For each batch [create a transaction](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html#building-a-transaction), add 100 payment operations (pay dividends to to every holder).
5. Submit the transaction to the network.
6. Rinse and repeat until you process all payments.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I take it there's no user-friendly solution via a wallet app perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move *actual* value into holders, I'd say the easiest way is buy-backs and burns. I.e, remove supply permanently from the market, and everyone's holdings become more valuable.

Comment: Great minds think alike - a buyback/burn combo strategy was indeed my first thought, as it has the added benefit of increasing both asset value and liquidity. Nonetheless, I had to at least pulse-check the dividend option.

Comment: And it's a lot less complicated in terms of operations needed. Just buy from the market, and then send back to the issuing account. You can even do it in one operation, as a path payment.

Comment: Awesome - I had not considered the path payment option; much simpler indeed. Thanks!