# How to check total supply of a trust-line based asset on the Stellar network?

Tags: stellar-sdk

How to know the total supply or the coins in circulation right now? Like in Ethereum we can check it with a predefined ERC20 function.

Comment: 1.Deploy your own Stellar Core node.

2.Query trustlines table of the underlying database directly to retrieve a list of your 
3.asset holders and the amount they hold.

4.Split the list in batches, 100 accounts per batch.

5.For each batch create a transaction, add 100 payment operations (pay dividends to to every holder).

6.Submit the transaction to the network.

7.Rinse and repeat until you process all payments.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good explanation on how to query the total supply of an asset created by an entity on Stellar's DEX [here](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/how-to-issue-a-dividend-in-stellar).

Once you have the result from the trustline query, you would iterate over all the asset holders, with their balances, and sum the balance amounts.